# Creating vertical wavesurfer

Tags: javascript, html, css

With below code clicks doesn't represent the correct audio timing. Some how it messes the click events of audio.

```css
        
#audiovisualizer {
    transform: translateX(100%) rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: top left;
}
```

```html
     

  <section id="audiovisualizer">
    <button onclick="wavesurfer.skipBackward()">
        Backward
    </button>

    <button onclick="wavesurfer.playPause()">
        Play | Pause
        <!-- <ion-icon name="play"></ion-icon> -->
    </button>

    <button onclick="wavesurfer.skipForward()">
        Forward
    </button>

    <button onclick="wavesurfer.toggleMute()">
        Toggle Mute
    </button>
    <div id="waveform"></div>
    <div id="waveform-timeline"></div>
</section>
```

Is there any other way to work this around. Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Please attach the whole code, where have you initialised the wavesurfer.js and called the wavesurfer function?

Comment: what do you mean by `doesn't represent the correct audio timing` ?